# How to throttle function using the mousewheel plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousewheel

I'm using this plugin:
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel

It's a horizontally scrolling one-page site, and the function is intended as a "scrollsnap"-- a scroll on the current section will force snap it to the next section. However, after the first "snap", it only happens after ~5 seconds, which I believe is due to the function firing too many times in a row.

```
function scrollSnap() {
    $('.page:not(:last-child)').each(function(){
        var nextTarget = $(this).next().position().left;
        $(this).mousewheel(function(){
            if(event.deltaY >= 50) {
                $('main').animate({
                    scrollLeft: nextTarget
                }, 700);
                console.log("scrolled to: ", nextTarget);
            }
        });
    });

    $('.page:not(:first-child)').each(function(){
        var prevTarget = $(this).prev().position().left;
        $(this).mousewheel(function(){
            if(event.deltaY <= -50) {
                $('main').animate({
                    scrollLeft: prevTarget
                }, 700);
                console.log("scrolled to: ", prevTarget);
            }
        });
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    scrollSnap();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can throttle events like these with something called a [debounce](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/debounce-in-javascript-improve-your-applications-performance-5b01855e086) function. You can create your own or use a utility library like [lodash](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/debounce-in-javascript-improve-your-applications-performance-5b01855e086) which has it built in.